Proper implementation of CDC_Transmit_FS
I created a project targeting STM32F4 in CubeIDE in which I want to use the USB CDC to communicate with the host computer. From the online tutorials, I know that we can use CDC_Transmit_FS function to send messages to the host. Here is the auto-generated code:
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
  uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 7 */
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;
  if (hcdc->TxState != 0){
    return USBD_BUSY;
  }
  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, Buf, Len);     // 1
  result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);   // 2
  /* USER CODE END 7 */
  return result;
}

Now I am getting Hard Fault (crash) which is apparently caused by the facts that

the buffer give it is locally allocated on the stack (inside a function call)
it is not clear but the supplied buffer is used asynchronously i.e. when the function CDC_Transmit_FS returns, the data might not be transmitted yet

so when the buffer is actually/eventually used in USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket (comment mark 2) it is no longer valid to use!
By allocating the buffer globally, I successfully send data over. But consecutive calls to CDC_Transmit_FS does not work due to asynchronous behavior above: To send a second message, I have to overwrite the global buffer.
That brings the question: How to modify this implementation to make it work? From what I can see

I need to use a global buffer to queuing the data to be sent.
In fact, in the function CDC_Init_FS generated by the IDE, there is a call SBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, UserTxBufferFS, 0); (with the wrong buffer size? shouldn't it be APP_TX_DATA_SIZE instead of 0?). Not sure why we have to keep calling USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer in CDC_Transmit_FS (comment mark 1).

I can append data to the buffer to queue it for transmission. (Keep track of the end pointer.)
But then I will eventually run out of space unless I know when the transmission is done and it is safe to start using the buffer from the beginning again. Also, of course there is concurrency issue: I could be 'adding' more data to the buffer while the transmission is going on so the additional data might get lost.


So what is a good solution to all this?

Do not append anything. It does not work like this. Check the global tx buffer and increa it size if needed (sometimes it has one packet size only. Also you need to trace USB IRQs to know when the buffer was actually transmitted on host request

Do not watch online tutorials. They are usually rubbish
